# Is there any benefit of having more badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

Just like having more reputation gives more power on SO, is there any benefit of having more badges?

Comment: They're shiny. They glitter like a teen vampire in daylight. What more do you need?

Comment: You get to have more badges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only to the extent that badges encourage *new* behaviors that are both positive for the community and for the user.

Comment: Or, in some cases, consolation prizes

Answer (score 3):

The happy feeling you get when you know that some machine somewhere values what you've done.

Comment: Jon Skeet values what I've done? ;)

Answer (score -1):

If the person asking a question has too few badges, and it takes more than a few minutes to answer the question, they **may** get less answers.

Comment: I have my doubts about that. Accept rate might lead to some inhibition, but random badge inventory?

Comment: I strongly disagree with this answer.

Comment: @bmargulies, I think having no badges or only 1 or 2 may have a effect, I agree that once someone has more then a few badges it will not have an effect